# Instantiate a class in only one class

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to make my life a little easier by off loading some of my `WinAPI` calls into another class. When doing so, I am getting a `.... is inaccessible due to its protection level`; it's obvious what the problem is. For example: I have a class that knows how to make a fishing pole, but this class should be the only class that knows how to make it and I feel the other's should not.

Here is the class I have currently...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace AeonianControls.DLL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides importing API functions and methods.
    /// </summary>
    public class APIHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Provides importing API functions and methods.
        /// </summary>
        public APIHelper()
        {

        }

        #region Imported DLL's
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the device context for the entire window.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window.</param>
        /// <returns>The handle to the device context for the window.</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
        /// <summary>
        /// Releases a device context.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window whose DC is to be released.</param>
        /// <param name="hDC">A handle to the DC to be released.</param>
        /// <returns>The return value indicates whether the DC was released. If the DC was released, the return value is 1 otherwise 0.</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the specified rectangle or region in a window's client area.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window to be redrawn.</param>
        /// <param name="lprc">A pointer to a RECT structure containing the coordinates, in device units, of the update rectangle. This parameter is ignored if the hrgnUpdate parameter identifies a region.</param>
        /// <param name="hrgn">A handle to the update region. If both the hrgnUpdate and lprcUpdate parameters are NULL, the entire client area is added to the update region.</param>
        /// <param name="flags">One or more redraw flags. This parameter can be used to invalidate or validate a window, control repainting, and control which windows are affected by RedrawWindow.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool RedrawWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lprc, IntPtr hrgn, uint flags);
        #endregion

        #region Methods and Functions

        #endregion

    }
}
```

***Here is the issue I am facing...***

I need to access this class and the methods in another class to use, **but** I do ***not*** want them to be instantiated in any other class, used or seen.

I have tried setting the methods to public which is fine, but I don't want them to be seen outside of the class I need them. I have tried making the constructor `private` and then a nested type, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a singleton pattern

```
public class APIHelper
{
    public readonly static APIHelper API = new APIHelper();
    private APIHelper()
    {
    }
    public void SomeMethod() { .. }
}
```

which is going to be used as follows

```
// Gain access through the API field
APIHelper.API.SomeMethod();
```

---

Maybe all you need is static fields. You need to clarify how you intent to use this class.

```
public static class APIHelper
{

    #region Imported DLL's
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the device context for the entire window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window.</param>
    /// <returns>The handle to the device context for the window.</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
    /// <summary>
    /// Releases a device context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window whose DC is to be released.</param>
    /// <param name="hDC">A handle to the DC to be released.</param>
    /// <returns>The return value indicates whether the DC was released. If the DC was released, the return value is 1 otherwise 0.</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the specified rectangle or region in a window's client area.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window to be redrawn.</param>
    /// <param name="lprc">A pointer to a RECT structure containing the coordinates, in device units, of the update rectangle. This parameter is ignored if the hrgnUpdate parameter identifies a region.</param>
    /// <param name="hrgn">A handle to the update region. If both the hrgnUpdate and lprcUpdate parameters are NULL, the entire client area is added to the update region.</param>
    /// <param name="flags">One or more redraw flags. This parameter can be used to invalidate or validate a window, control repainting, and control which windows are affected by RedrawWindow.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RedrawWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lprc, IntPtr hrgn, uint flags);
    #endregion

}
```

this is now used as

```
var ptr = APIHelper.GetWindowDC(hdc);
```

Comment: Interesting, never thought of the singleton pattern. When I do this, I get `... is inaccessible due to its protection level`. For example: `var hdc = APIHelper.API.GetWindowDC(this.Handle);` thats how im using it. And the function I am calling is: `[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);` If I add public then its a different error.

Comment: What is inaccessible? the class, the methods and the `static` field `API` all are public?

Comment: I was under the impression you wanted to wrap the `extern` calls

Comment: The dll imports for the api calls. No I dont want to wrap them, but I can't call them...

Comment: Would I have to wrap each one in a method?

Comment: It depends. You would have a class with field if you want to keep some data between calls. If not, then just use public static methods in a static class. See my edit now.

Comment: Got it! Sorry about the trouble the singleton and just having the statics work well. Thank you again!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree. If it's stateless the static class should do it as I mention in the post.

Comment: So why do you say that a singleton should be used?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The _OP_ can choose based on his requirements. There is nothing wrong with a stateless singleton, other than it adds an unnecessary layer to the API. The question wasn't clear if there is a state or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want...

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides importing API functions and methods.
/// </summary>
internal class APIHelper
{
/// <summary>
/// Provides importing API functions and methods.
/// </summary>
internal APIHelper()
{

}

#region Imported DLL's
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves the device context for the entire window.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window.</param>
/// <returns>The handle to the device context for the window.</returns>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
/// <summary>
/// Releases a device context.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window whose DC is to be released.</param>
/// <param name="hDC">A handle to the DC to be released.</param>
/// <returns>The return value indicates whether the DC was released. If the DC was released, the return value is 1 otherwise 0.</returns>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
/// <summary>
/// Updates the specified rectangle or region in a window's client area.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window to be redrawn.</param>
/// <param name="lprc">A pointer to a RECT structure containing the coordinates, in device units, of the update rectangle. This parameter is ignored if the hrgnUpdate parameter identifies a region.</param>
/// <param name="hrgn">A handle to the update region. If both the hrgnUpdate and lprcUpdate parameters are NULL, the entire client area is added to the update region.</param>
/// <param name="flags">One or more redraw flags. This parameter can be used to invalidate or validate a window, control repainting, and control which windows are affected by RedrawWindow.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool RedrawWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lprc, IntPtr hrgn, uint flags);
#endregion

#region Methods and Functions

#endregion

}
```

It doesn't do exactly what you describe.  The internal keyword will prevent visibility of the methods in your helper class outside of of the assembly the class is in.  This should be good enough.  If you really need to hide these methods from everyone else then put the 2 classes in an assembly by themselves.